# How to define member class operator based on the class parameters

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11

Is it possible to define different = operators for different template arguments. Let's assume that I want to use different methods for converting arguments of different types:

```
template <class T,class U>
class cTest
{
  private:
  public:
    T x;
    U y;

  //typical case
  cTest<T,U>& operator =(const cTest<T,U> &that)
  {
     return *this;
  }

  //operator = based on the LHS type 1
  cTest<uint16_t,U>& operator =(const cTest<int,U> &that)
  {
     cout<<"cTest<uint16_t,U>& operator =(const cTest<int,U> &that)"<<endl;
     return cTest<uint16_t,U>();
   }
  //operator = based on the LHS type 2
   cTest<uint8_t,U>& operator =(const cTest<int,U> &that)
   {
      cout<<"cTest<uint8_t,U>& operator =(const cTest<int,U> &that)"<<endl;
      return cTest<uint16_t,U>();
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to overload operators/functions by return type.  This is not allowed by the C++ standard:

> **13.1/2:** Certain function declarations cannot be overloaded: — Function declarations that differ only in the return type cannot be
>   overloaded.

***Possible workarounds:***

- You could consider using a function instead on an operator, passing by reference a variable for storing the return value.  In this case the overload would be possible.  But it's less handy than the assignment operator, and I guess that's no what you were looking for.
- A better approach would be to add a separate conversion operator between `cTest<uint16_t,U>` and `cTest<uint8_t,U>`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you have a look at [Template Metaprogramming](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3743/A-gentle-introduction-to-Template-Metaprogramming).

> Template Metaprogramming is a generic programming technique that uses extremely early binding. The compiler acts as an interpreter or a "virtual computer" that emits the instructions that make up the final program. It can be used for static configuration, adaptive programs, optimization and much more.

You can basically let the compiler decide what template definition to use, depending on the respective values. An example for a quaternion multiplication would look like:

```
template <typename Quaternion>
typename std::enable_if_t<sds::is_quaternion<Quaternion>::value, Quaternion>
operator+(const Quaternion &a, const Quaternion &b)
{
    return Quaternion
        (
            a.u() + b.u(),
            a.v() + b.v()
        );
}
```